# Configure trino-jvm properties in GCP Dataproc on cluster create

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, trino, dataproc

I'm trying to configure trino-jvm properties while creating a Dataproc cluster.  I'm following [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/trino) and am able to successfully create a cluster without any special JVM configuration, but am receiving an error when attempting to configure JVM properties.

Here's the CLI command that running:

```bash
gcloud dataproc clusters create test-dataproc-cluster \
    --project=MY_PROJECT \
    --optional-components=TRINO \
    --region=region \
    --enable-component-gateway \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --image-version=2.1 \
    --properties="trino-jvm:XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

Here's the error that I receive:

```bash
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) argument --properties: Bad syntax for dict arg: [trino-jvm:XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError]. Please see `gcloud topic flags-file` or `gcloud topic escaping` for information on providing list or dictionary flag values with special characters.
```

It looks like Dataproc expects the value to the `--properties` argument to be in dictionary form, i.e. `--properties=TYPE:KEY=VALUE`.  I'm able to successfully configure other properties that have a Key/Value syntax.  However, I'm unable to configure JVM properties that do not follow that Key/Value form.

How can I configure trino-jvm properties in Dataproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `--properties` flag command  flag to specify the Trino JVM property trino.jvm-extras=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError. The property is provided in the format key=value.

```
--properties trino-env-config=trino.jvm-extras=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

Aside from **--properties flag**, one workaround to fix the error it by using the `--metadata flag` because it can accept multiple key-value pairs. It  can provide the necessary JVM properties for Trino in Dataproc clusters during cluster creation.

```
--metadata trino-jvm=XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```